# JavaScript - How to use ` ` in java script properly?

Tags: javascript

I have one question about the use of  in javascript. 
I have code that looks something like this:

HTML code:

```
<select onchange="indicator(this)">
<option  value =" " selected="selected">STANDARDOWE</option>
<option id="1" value ="cci">CCI</option>
<option id="1" value="obv">OBV</option>
<option value="mfi">MFI</option>
<option value="atr">ATR</option>
<option id="1" value="bbands">BB</option>
<option value="momentum">MOM</option>
<option value="macd">MACD</option>
<option value="psar">SA</option>
```

And a function indicator in js:

```
function indicator(s){
var value = s[s.selectedIndex].value;
console.log("value" + " " + value);

   if(value === "cci"){
   chart.plot(0).cci(mapping)
}
if(value ==="obv"){
     chart.plot(0).obv(mapping)
}
if(value === "mfi"){
    chart.plot(0).mfi(mapping).series()
}
if(value ==="atr"){
     chart.plot(0).atr(mapping).series();
}
if(value === "bbands"){
    chart.plot(0).bbands(mapping)
}
if(value === "momentum"){
    chart.plot(0).momentum(mapping).series();
}
if(value === "macd"){
    chart.plot(0).macd(mapping, 12, 26, 9);
}
if(value === "psar"){
     chart.plot(0).psar(mapping, 0.08, 0.60, 0.10).series();
}
}
```

But I want to shorten the function and have something like this:

```
function indicator(s){
var value = s[s.selectedIndex].value;
console.log("value" + " " + value);
{`chart.plot(0)${value}(mapping)`}
}
```

but it is not working. I tried to write it down as above and do:

```
  chart.plot(0){'${value}'}(mapping)
```

but it still doesn't work.

How to write ' ' properly?

Comment: Can you try `chart.plot(0)[value](mapping)`  ?

Comment: Do you mean a blank space or actually a \``

Comment: newie, just for some context, `` is for outputting strings. Rudolf Cicko's comment is the way to go if you want to call functions by a variable name.

Comment: @RudolfCicko thanks, it's works :) I didn't figure it out. :)

Answer (score 1):

The backquotes are used in javascript to create a template string (see [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for further reference).

Template strings are pretty similar to common strings, but there are two major differences:

A) They can be multiline, so you can actually break lines inside of them.

B) You can use interpolation with the `${value}` syntax to add dynamic values in your string without all the unnecessary concats.

That being said, in your example you don't need to use those strings. You can just  use the bracket syntax to access your object properties, like this:

```
chart.plot(0)[value](mapping);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to use `` here.

```
function indicator(s){
  var value = s[s.selectedIndex].value;
  return chart.plot(0)[value](mapping);
  // return chart.plot(0)[`${value}`](mapping); // if you want if with back ticks 
}
```

will work.

Answer (score 0):

When you write the sentence "${}" inside a string like `` you are telling to Javascript that execute the content of "${}", for example if you write:

```js
console.log(`${1+2}`);
// The result is print '3'
```

Whatever, if you want to call the function dynamic you should write it this way.

```js
chart.plot(0)[value](mapping);
```

And if you want to call it into a `` sentence :

```js
console.log(`result: ${chart.plot(0)[value](mapping)}`)
```